# find $E(X\mid X < c) $ for $X\sim\exp(\theta)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim\exp(\theta)$ ie  $$f(x;\theta) = \frac 1 \theta e^{-x/\theta}$$

compute $E(X\mid X < c)$ for some constant $c$

Comment: 3+ years on the site, 80+ questions asked, and you post this zero-context do-my-hwk-for-me-asap-plz stuff?

Comment: LOL this is like one part of a bigger question involving the EM Algorithm, I posted this question earlier with my solution attempt (which i am pretty sure is correct), and asked if anyone could verify the solution but no one did, so I posted it again, hoping someone could help, and get a -2 down vote. If I screw up this expected value, the whole algoirthm doesnt work so I am just making sure. What is the point of this site if you're just gonna bash anyone who asks a question? @Did

Comment: How do you know that I am "just gonna bash anyone who asks a question"? Is this a free accusation meant to avoid addressing the point or what? // So, if I understand you correctly, this is a no-context question **and** a deliberate duplicate? Two reasons to close it, it seems.

Comment: what context would you like? Its for a part of the EM algorithm... and I am only posting it twice because a couple days had past and no one responded, so I knew there was no hope. For the record, I ended up using my solution and the algorithm worked. I only came back on to delete the question... @Did

Comment: Perfect, this will save us the work (but your answerer will be delighted, I guess). Anyway, next time, try to follow the rules of the site instead of bending them.

Answer (score 1):

For any Borel set $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ with $\mathbb P(X\in A)>0$, by definition,
$$E(X\mid X\in A)=\frac{E\left[X \cdot \mathbf 1_{(X\in A)}\right]}{\mathbb P(X\in A)} = \frac{\int_A x \cdot f_X(x)\,dx}{\mathbb P(X\in A)}.$$

Use this formula and calculate the result.